# How can I convert a gtk.ListStore to list?

Tags: python, pygtk

I have a GUI with a gtk.TreeView and I would like to convert the gtk.ListStore to python list, how can I do that?

Comment: A `gtk.ListStore` is (roughly) a list of rows, each row being a list of values (one per column). Do you mean you want to generate a list of lists?

Comment: for example I have a class which expecting a list not a gtk.ListStore

Comment: Does that class expect a list of rows (i.e. a list of lists)? Otherwise, I'm afraid the two data types are unrelated.

Comment: yes it's expecting a list of lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
rowList = [column for column in [row for row in yourListStore]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a more neat implementation would be:

```
list_store_data = [list(row) for row in list_store]
```